# Visual Studio 2010, Error indication before compile/debug

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I am creating my first C# project in Visual Studio 2010. (I am obligated to use 2010 because of company policy and did only vb.net projects in the past).

Problem: Visual Studio Error Window doesn't display **all** errors while the code is written. The errors do appear - but only when I press F5.

- E.g. "Invalid token '}' in class" does appear while writing the code.
- E.g. "class does not implement interface member" - does appear *at
  compile time only*

Questions:

- Is Visual Studio 2010 able to detect this error in C# while creating the code at all? (in vb.net there will be an error while creating the code)
- Do I need to enable some error checking option because I switched from
  vb.net to C#? (Tools > Options > Text Editor > C# > Advanced > Editor Help Options are all checked)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Its should detect : "Invalid token '}' in class" though

Comment: Infact It should detect both the errors hes mentioned in the post

Comment: Visual Studio dedects this error in a vb.net projects while creating the code:
"Class xyz must implement 'Proptery abc as String' for interface 'aaa'."

Answer (score -1):

Yes it definitely should be able to tell you errors as you go.
Its hard to say why yours is not working from the question above i would try rebuilding the solution or restarting visual studio.

Also make sure your error window has these settings :
[image]

Comment: Unfortunately rebuild or reopen doesn't help. 
Visual Studio 2010 doesn't have the options Build + InelliSense.
But it does show me the error for vb.net projects.